# Add Material Icon in angular-library

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my library-component I use material-icon with custom icon list.
I registry my icon:

```
constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { 
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon('info', this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`./info.svg`));
  }
```

But after bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl my path looking as localhost:4200/info.svg.
I need to get my svg icon from library assets.

Comment: Well, why don't you exchange './info.svg' with '/assets/info.svg'?

Comment: It will search in main project assets, not in my library assets

Comment: You mean your icon is located somewhere in node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes, I want to add icon in my library component